# Cannot get swagger xml comments to work (web api 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

swagger is working, but not xml comments. Have made the following change to SwaggerConfig.cs:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
         c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Web.API");
         c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\SwaggerTesting.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
    });
```

Have edited the properties of the project to point to bin folder.

Done this in controller:

```
  ///<Summary>
    /// Get these comments
    ///</Summary>
    [Route("year/{year:int:length(4)}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQueryAttribute]  
    public IHttpActionResult GetReviewsByYear(int year)
```

Comment: Does the file SwaggerTesting.XML exists in your bin folder?

Comment: hi @CodeNotFound, yes. If I remove it the rendering web page says it cannot be found...

Comment: If it exists it should work. Where do you look at the comment? Also open the file and check if the comments are there :)

Comment: It exists, but does not work! The controllers/methods work in swagger, but theie comments are missing